Bougainvillea bare
I bought a 5ft bougainvillea from a nursery and the moment I took it home it started getting spider mites. I sprayed it with insecticidal soap and it was doing fine. But then I had a few days of windy and rainy weather and the bougainvillea’s leaves and bracts all dropped. It’s completely bare and I assumed it was from all the rain. I decided to repot it into a terracotta pot to help it dry out faster. However it’s still bare and some of the smaller branches where the leaves and bracts grew turned brown. I decided to prune those off and some of the stalks but I don’t see it showing new blooms or leaves at the nodes. The plant is still alive because if I scratch the bark it’s still green inside but I have no idea what to do.
For reference I live in southern Ontario near Toronto so the weather is now warming up but we’ve had several days of temp fluctuations.
